# How to delete entries in DynamoDb having a specified prefix

Tags: database-design, amazon-dynamodb, key-value-store

In [BatchWriteItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html) we can do only `DeleteRequest` and `PutRequest` and `DeleteRequest` is only about a single key. However, we may want to delete all keys having a specified prefix.

The expensive solution to that problem is to download all the keys of a specific prefix using a key_condition_expression. Then we would issue the corresponding list of `DeleteRequest` in `BatchWriteItem`.

Is there a better way? What would be the right way to architecture a `DynamoDb` database in order to be able to do that?

Comment: TTL is free and might be helpful if your use case fits its purpose -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TTL.html

Answer (score 1):

In DynamoDB to do any sort of Put/Update/Delete you have to know the entire primary key (Partition and Sort key).

For that reason you would need to read the items first to obtain the full key for items which match your filter logic and use BatchWriteItem to delete up to 25 items per batch.

Comment: Thank you. It feels like a weakness of DynamoDb. But so be it.

Comment: Indeed. Some other databases which share DynamoDB's data model of having partition keys and sort keys in each partition, like Cassandra and ScyllaDB, do allow you to efficiently delete an entire partition and all its sort keys given just the partition key. Unfortunately, and somewhat surprisingly, DynamoDB does not have this operation.

Comment: I will provide your feedback to the team. Thank you.